# Generic Property on TypeScript with subset of optional properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I have a generic key where the key name must be one of the established options and also limit so when one of the keys is assigned, the others can't be assigned anymore.

E.g.

```
interface State {
  key: string;
  location: string;
  ['item_id' | 'item2_id' | 'item3_id']: number; //Example
};

I could only assign one of these three values. 
One of them must be assigned, and only one of them can be assigned to the State.

state = {
  key: '1';
  location: 'description';
  item1_id: 1; 
} // OK

state = {
  key: '1';
  location: 'description';
  item4_id: 1; 
} // Error.

state = {
  key: '1';
  location: 'description';
  item1_id: 1; 
  item2_id: 2; 
} // Error.
```

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you need this. Having an interface where you aren't sure which keys will or will not be present seems to somewhat defeat the purpose of having the interface, no?

Comment: I want to make sure only one of these three keys are passed in.
I could do something like:

```interface State {
  key: string;
  location: string;
  item_id?: number;
  item2_id?: number;
  intem3_id?:number;
};```
But that would give the possibility to assign all three items or none.

Comment: I understand that, but an interface is a contract for a class to follow. It just seems like a smell to me when you have a class that implements this interface, yet have no idea if it has `item_id`, `item2_id`, or `item3_id`.

Comment: I understand. Do you have any suggestion on what could be the best approach for something like that? Thanks @TylerRoper

Comment: Hard without knowing the true use-case, but rather than `item3_id: 5` for example, could you use two properties: `item: 3, item_id: 5`? That way you know that every implementation of this interface will _always_ have the `item` and `item_id` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is really the structure you want (and you can't refactor to something easier for TS to understand), you're going to want `State` to end up as a [union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of multiple types, each one of which has exactly one of those properties while the other properties are explicitly disallowed (well, the closest you'll get is that if they are present they have to have an `undefined` values).

One way to programmatically define this sort of exactly-one-key union is this:

```
type ExactlyOneKey<K extends PropertyKey, V> = { [P in K]:
    (Record<P, V> & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>) extends infer O ?
    { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] } : never }[K];
```

That basically iterates over each key in `K` and produces a type where the `K` property is of type `V` and the other properties are optional properties of type `never`.  Let's see what it does on a test example:

```
type Test = ExactlyOneKey<'a' | 'b' | 'c', boolean>;
/* type Test = {
    a: boolean;
    b?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
} | {
    b: boolean;
    a?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
} | {
    c: boolean;
    a?: undefined;
    b?: undefined;
} */
```

See how each element of that union has one defined property and two prohibited ones.  Now we can define `State`.  This will have to be a `type` alias instead of an `interface` because the latter cannot be a union:

```
type State = {
    key: string,
    location: string,
} & ExactlyOneKey<'item1_id' | 'item2_id' | 'item3_id', number>;
```

Let's see how it works on your examples:

```
state = {
    key: '1',
    location: 'description',
    item1_id: 1,
} // OK

state = {
    key: '1',
    location: 'description',
    item4_id: 1, // error here, unknown key
} // Error.

state = { // error here, not assignable to State
    key: '1',
    location: 'description',
    item1_id: 1,
    item2_id: 2,
} // Error.
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwMbADYgPIDsIGkIgA8uUEcwEWAJgM5QAKATgPaSOj4gA0UAagHxQAvFADeUANr0oASyxRcAXQBcAKCgaoACgBKEJM0ZVC9HgKgAyBgnYyEqQnoNHC8JKgCuVCMR71+PDgAbhCM-PwAlKTklLSyWABmoVAYUAD86priEgCK8VAA1gTMCSkqKbmKUAC+UMpQwcnVEkoA3KqqoJBQACoQNMDCsIgo6Nh4BIQA5AhTUAA+UFMARnOLU0hTPMvMzKgQCFj87QD0AFRQXdB9A0OimRoI9Tt7B1jtmlDLafUe1BAJOQQKgfTRIH5QP7eQE4EGqWqLe6fZbPXb7Q6gx4QqEAoFwz7g37-GHA9oIsQPKBIVGvDGUhDY4l4zFfRnQ5nwqBnE4dK5QADKwAQFDulKKIHqA0YcgA5lxKahmEhhTJmFhJcBpVg5ZyrPBkGhMDhONMZBQALYARgA+jIqGslmaIOaAEy2+0LR0WgDM7q2DQ85uWoWOHX2gwGwog9UFUdaUA6kZFIiRmnF9Smlq2CqVKrVGe8NCQ0rAwFVWGznydVvd9Ut8tqJxOKVwiaFyYpn3TSyz8s+iuVZfzS0LxZkpfLlc01YALLWoPWoE3SIwWIwoAALUIQHh-ApYZgAd3k4s5y5gq8MADo21G7kvm6E15vt4FmIMEDQaDIZVgEMt9kuZgBXbCAxQIDNexzQdywLfoxwnNUpw0asbTtOs+2nC03XQqAXQbB9YEvRgbw6MiOiAA)